# rust: link.exe not found

Tags: visual-studio, rust

I installed the rust compiler and also **MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.27)** (as an individual component)
[image]

This does not seam to be working.

[image]

Does rust require anything more which I have not installed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The following thread seems to be related: [Unable to compile Rust hello world on Windows: linker link.exe not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603112/1113913). Perhaps it is of help.

Comment: Although that is related, I am actually trying to find the minimum components for rust to work. It seems like the C++ build tools install lots of stuff.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in this article?: [Use the Microsoft C++ toolset from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Install the Windows SDK too.

I also didn't want to install all of Visual Studio just to compile rust from the command line.

Based on the info in [coder-256's link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019), I tried running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat`.  Then, instead of being unable to find `link.exe`, I got the error:
`note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'advapi32.lib'`

Searching Stack for that error led to this answer: [Install the Windows SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505627/7351717)

So I installed the Windows 10 SDK, and now (after launching a new cmd window) it works.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I've been searching for :)

Make sure to use the matching SDK for the Window version you're using, i.e. W10 = W10 SDK

Answer (score 0):

Using Win11, here's the specific steps that worked for me (assumes VSCode and Rust are already installed):

1. Go to the [Visual Studio Download site](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202019&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads)
2. Download Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.9)
3. Install
4. Create a "hello world" Rust project (`cargo new hello`)
5. Open project in VSCode
6. Set path info in launch.json file (located at folder root, may need to create this first)
7. Type Shift+Ctrl+B to build the Rust project