# Rust and Python on W10: LNK1181

Tags: python, rust, windows-10, rust-cargo, toolchain

I'm trying to write a Rust module which can be called from Python. I'm following this page:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/11/16/speed-python-using-rust#edit_src_lib_rs

On `cargo build --release` I get this error:

> = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file
> 'python39.lib'

This has come up before, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505627/595305) seems the most recent and relevant answer.

I seem to have tried all the possible solutions in that answer, including locating and running vcvars64.bat, as detailed [here](http://asyncbulbs.blogspot.com/2017/06/workaround-for-rustc-with-new-visual.html). No joy.

I have MS Visual Studio (2019) installed, with the C++ and W10 SDK components.

Significantly, ***this error sometimes does not occur when I don't include the*** `--release` ***switch***. Without it, the program (sometimes) compiles and runs OK. Given that one reason for wanting to make a Rust module is performance, however, I'd like to solve this problem. Also I have now found that this successul building of a "debug" build is a) intermittent and b) partial: when it fails, some of the desired output files are created but not others.

And...

According to the page at the first link, it seems that after `build`, I should then be looking for a file ending .so. In a W10 OS I'm looking for a .dll file.

If it builds completely successfully, under target\debug I have myrustlib.d, myrustlib.dll, myrustlib.dll.exp, myrustlib.dll.lib, myrustlib.pdb, pyext_myrustlib.pdb, pyext_myrustlib.d and pyext_myrustlib.exe. None of these, renamed and/or given an .dll extension as applicable, can be successfully imported as a Python module, at least as documented on that page.

I've also found [this more recent page](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-rust-to-extend-python-360174ee5819) for doing the same thing. I get the same 1181 error.

**python39.lib**

I found out where this is located in my system, under ... Python\Python39\libs. I modified my PATH env var to specifically include this path (and rebooted). Still the same error.

Comment: Hmm no idea. But the file is available in my installation directory in Python\libs\python39.lib. Maybe reinstall CPython with pretty much every option turned on?, best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

[This page](https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/08/10/python-extensions-in-pure-rust-with-pyo3/), using [PyO3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3) instead of rust-cpython (actually a fork of the latter), appears to do things successfully, on my machine + OS at least.

NB at the time of writing the second example appears to contain a typo: I believe it should be

```
fn hashset(_: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
```

rather than

```
fn hash_set(_: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
```

if you want it to compile OK (author has been notified). I have managed to create a module (hashset.cp39-win_amd64.pyd in a W10 OS) which successfully enables you to import this Rust construct into Python.